Higher geodesics using higher parallel transport on higher bundles?
I was reading a lot of material on geodesics lately, and I was wondering what kind of abstract generalizations would make sense. Since connections on a 2-bundle exist (and generalizations to n-bundles I guess), as well as higher parallel transport, would higher geodesics defined from these make any sense?

If that is the case, does the notion appear in any paper or book?
If that is not the case, then why does it make no sense?

